# Anonymous package publish worked with npm 6.x but not works with npm 8.x

Tags: node.js, npm, artifactory, npm-publish

We used to publish package by using **npm publish --registry=https://sampleur.com/api/npm**, we don't have any auth token in .npmrc file it works in npm 6.x version.

Recently we upgrade npm to 8.x after this upgrade this command not works, it throws **ENEEDAUTH** error.

Our artifactory has access to anonymous user to publish. We are maintaining artifacts in internal jFrog application. Npm publish works with node 6.x but not with 8.x.

I want to understand is auth token mandatory to publish npm package in npm 8.x version even registry has anonymous access? If not how to publish it?

Answer (score -1):

Jfrog recently (1. July) deactivated all free tier accounts. You might have to upgrade to a paid plan

Comment: I think, there is no issue with jFrog, npm publish works properly with npm 6.x

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).